# python recurrence relation how to make definite loop and print all the results line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, recurrence

To all of the geniuses with good heart, I have tried to solve the following recurrence relation and really tried my best. `r` is float, which would a input value, and `t` is an integer, which is time(seconds), and `s` is also an input value (a float).

```
t(i+1)=rt(i)(1-ti), t1 = input value
```

I have to print `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`, `t5`, `t6~ t(s-1)` line by line

What I've found difficult is that I can't make some proper definite loop.

```html
d = float(input('density'))
r = float(input('parameter'))
s = int(input('seconds'))
t = int()
print(d)
a = int()
while 2 < a <= s - 1
    a = 2
    return_result = r*d*(1-d)
    print(return_result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The syntax for loops is to end with a colon ":"

2) Multiple comparisons must be joined by "and" or "or"

3) The control variable for a loop needs to be updated within the loop so that you don't end up in an infinite loop.

Syntax updates:

```
while 2 < a and a <= s - 1:
    #calculations
    a += 1
```

Comment: I already tried this ...nothing desirable came out..I'm sorry my friend.